# Вывод результатов теста на JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html5

При нажатии на кнопку "результат" необходимо, чтобы появлялся новый блок div, в котором содержалась следующая информация (примерно):
"Количество верных ответов: prav
Ваша оценка: "(в зависимости от prav по шкале
От 0 до 1 правильных ответов - оценка "2"
2 правильных ответа - оценка "3"
3 правильных ответа - оценка "4"
От 4 до 5 правильных ответов - оценка "5")
Пока код имеет следующий вид:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<html lang='ru'> 
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<head>  
<title> Script+function </title>
<script> 
let prav = 0; 
function prom1(){ 
    var otvet1 = prompt("Вопрос 1. Шотландия занимает ... часть Великобритании.","Введите пропущенное слово"); 
if(otvet1 == "северную"){ 
  prav = prav + 1 
} 
} 
function prom2(){ 
    var otvet2 = prompt("Вопрос 2. На территории Шотландии официальными считаются английский, англо-шотландский и шотландский ... языки.","Введите пропущенное слово"); 
if(otvet2 == "кельтский"){ 
  prav = prav + 1 
} 
} 
function prom3(){ 
    var otvet3 = prompt("Вопрос 3. Какой город является столицей Шотландии?","Введите слово"); 
if(otvet3 == "Эдинбург"){ 
  prav = prav + 1 
} 
} 
function prom4(){ 
    var otvet4 = prompt("Вопрос 4. Порядок слов в кельтских языках: сказуемое, ... , дополнение.","Введите пропущенное слово"); 
if(otvet4 == "подлежащее"){ 
  prav = prav + 1 
} 
} 
function prom5(){ 
    var otvet5 = prompt("Вопрос 5. В шотландском языке ... гласных, чем в английском.","Введите пропущенное слово"); 
if(otvet5 == "больше"){ 
  prav = prav + 1 
} 
} 
 
</script> 
</head> 
<body>    
<h1>  Тест на тему "Шотландия. Шотланский язык" </h1> 
<p>Данный тест направлен на проверку знаний, полученных на предыдущих страницах. Ваша задача - вписать ответ в окно</p> 
  <br>Правила выставления оценки: 
  <br>От 0 до 1 правильных ответов - оценка "2" 
  <br>2 правильных ответа - оценка "3" 
  <br>3 правильных ответа - оценка "4" 
  <br>От 4 до 5 правильных ответов - оценка "5" 
<p>Удачи в прохождении теста!</p> 
<button id="1" onclick="prom1()">Вопрос 1</button> 
<br> 
<button id="2" onclick="prom2()">Вопрос 2</button> 
<br> 
<button id="3" onclick="prom3()">Вопрос 3</button> 
<br> 
<button id="4" onclick="prom4()">Вопрос 4</button> 
<br> 
<button id="5" onclick="prom5()">Вопрос 5</button> 
  <br> 
</body>  
</html>
```

Желательно более или менее простой способ именно на js

Comment: Где кнопка "Результат" и где должен появляться новый div? И если всё нужно на JS, то может быть создать объект/класс для вопросов/ответов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Расчет оценки реализовал через `switch`, а вывод результата в  `div` с помощью `document.getElementById("resultBox").innerHTML` через ид `div`'а.

Также сами вопросы лучше отображать сразу а не через `prompt` и добавил при подтверждении ответа блокировку поля ввода.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <html lang='ru'>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    
    <head>
        <title> Script+function </title>
        <script>
            let prav = 0;
            function prom1() {
                if (document.getElementById("edit1").value == "северную")
                    prav++;
                document.getElementById("btn1").disabled = true;
                document.getElementById("edit1").disabled = true;
            }
            function prom2() {
                if (document.getElementById("edit2").value == "кельтский")
                    prav++;
                document.getElementById("btn2").disabled = true;
                document.getElementById("edit2").disabled = true;
            }
            function prom3() {
                if (document.getElementById("edit3").value == "Эдинбург")
                    prav++;
                document.getElementById("btn3").disabled = true;
                document.getElementById("edit3").disabled = true;
                console.log(prav)
            }
            function prom4() {
                if (document.getElementById("edit4").value == "подлежащее")
                    prav++;
                document.getElementById("btn4").disabled = true;
                document.getElementById("edit4").disabled = true;
            }
            function prom5() {
                if (document.getElementById("edit5").value == "больше")
                    prav++;
                document.getElementById("btn5").disabled = true;
                document.getElementById("edit5").disabled = true;
            }
            function GetResult() {
                var estimation = 0;
                switch (prav) {
                    case 0:
                    case 1:
                        estimation = 2;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        estimation = 3;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        estimation = 4;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                    case 5:
                        estimation = 5;
                        break;
                }
                document.getElementById("resultBox").innerHTML += "<br>Количество верных ответов: " + prav + " Ваша оценка: " + estimation;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <h1> Тест на тему "Шотландия. Шотланский язык" </h1>
        <p>Данный тест направлен на проверку знаний, полученных на предыдущих страницах. Ваша задача - вписать ответ в окно
        </p>
        <p>Удачи в прохождении теста!</p>
    
        <div>
            <b>Вопрос 1. Шотландия занимает ... часть Великобритании.</b>
            <br>Введите пропущенное слово.
            <br><input id="edit1" /><button id="btn1" onclick="prom1()">Ответить</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <b>Вопрос 2. На территории Шотландии официальными считаются английский, англо-шотландский и шотландский ...
                языки.</b>
            <br>Введите пропущенное слово.
            <br><input id="edit2" /><button id="btn2" onclick="prom2()">Ответить</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <b>Вопрос 3. Какой город является столицей Шотландии?</b>
            <br>Введите слово
            <br><input id="edit3" /><button id="btn3" onclick="prom3()">Ответить</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <b>Вопрос 4. Порядок слов в кельтских языках: сказуемое, ... , дополнение.</b>
            <br>Введите пропущенное слово.
            <br><input id="edit4" /><button id="btn4" onclick="prom4()">Ответить</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <b>Вопрос 5. В шотландском языке ... гласных, чем в английском.</b>
            <br>Введите пропущенное слово.
            <br><input id="edit5" /><button id="btn5" onclick="prom5()">Ответить</button>
        </div>
        <div id="resultBox">
            <br><button onclick="GetResult()">Результат</button>
        </div>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```